# How to iterate over indices instead of elements?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to make a function that takes a given array and searches it for the first occurence of a sequence of at least two numbers. The sequence starts with a higher number, then drops to a lower one then growing, something like this: 6 6 3 3 4 5 5 6.

Next I have to put it into a different array, printing it out afterwards.

I tried doing this:

```
 for e in sub_array:
    length = 0
    while e > e+1 or e+1 <= e+2:
        res.append(e)
        length += 1
        e += 1
    if length >= 2:
        return res
    else:
        res = []
return res
```

, but it uses [e] as an element instead of an index, returning nothing (putting e in square brackets does not solve the problem).

For example, if I put in something like [2, 9, 6, 2, 5, 7, 7, 3], it must return [6, 2, 5, 7, 7], but the function returns an empty array []

Any tips on how I can make this work?

Edit: I am not tied to using indices, I'm searching for any way to make this work. I'm just trying to figure out how to solve this problem in the most efficient way.

Comment: Don't overwrite builtins like `len` with your own definitions

Comment: Is your question "how to iterate over indices instead of elements"? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). It's not clear what you want your code to do or what the problem is. Maybe adding example input and output will help. Please also describe how the current code falls short ("breaking it all" is insufficient description)

Comment: Do you actually need indices? This could be solved by iterating on the overlapping *pairs* of elements.

Comment: Just to point out where you went wrong, `e+1` is not the value of the next element.  It's literally the current value plus one.  `e` will always be less than `e+1` and `e+1` will always be less than `e+2`.

Comment: The hacky way to do what you want is to do `for e in range(len(sub_array)-1):`, and then check `sub_array[e]` and `sub_array[e+1]`.  The cute way is to use `zip(e,e[1:])`.  Have you used zip?

Comment: @TimRoberts figured it out myself, but I dont see a way to make it work. I tried doing "for e in range(sub_array)" but it just gives out " 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm afraid I am not yet familiar with zip, so Id like to avoid using what I don't yet know. I tried the hacky suggestion, but it sees len as a variable instead of a function and does not work

Comment: That's a bug on your part.  Do not name your own variables `len` or `int` or `str` or `map` or any other word with meaning to Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts fixed the bug by making a new project, but now a new thing emerged: it only drops the first [e] into res instead of the needed sequence, even though I'm pretty sure that the requirements for the while loop are correct

Comment: Why isn't [9,6] a valid answer for your example?  That's clearly the first case where a higher number is followed by a lower number.

Comment: @TimRoberts [9,6] is valid too, sorry for bad math here, deep-fried brain with this thing, this piece is just a function in a bigger project

Comment: Its not super obvious what condition you are looking for in your search. if you are searching for a specific set of numbers - the laziest thing is to cast your array of integers to string and do a find.  `str(arr).find('9,6')`

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem as you have stated it.  The loop can be in several states: searching for a pair that goes down, gathering, and finding a pair that goes down while gathering.

```
def find_sequence(array):
    last = None
    found = []
    for e in array:
        # If this is the first element, save it for next time.
        if last is None:
            last = e
        elif not found:
            # If we have not found a sequence and numbers are increasing,
            # just save and check for next time.
            if e >= last:
                last = e
            # Otherwise, we have the start of a new potential sequence.
            else:
                found = [last, e]
        # If we are in the middle of gathering a sequence and a number
        # goes down, that's the end of the sequence.
        elif e < found[-1]:
            break
        # Otherwise, add the number to the sequence.
        else:
            found.append(e)
    return found

array = [2,4,6,2,5,7,7,3]
print(find_sequence(array))
print(find_sequence([6,7,7,3,4,5,6,6,7,2]))
```

Comment: Hello again. The code is all right and it is working pretty well, but there are some specific problem that I found. For example, if I put in an array [6,7,7,3,4,5,6,6,7,2], I want to get an output of [7,7,3,4,5,6,6,7], but I get [7,3,4,5,6,6]. So, it cuts off any repeating numbers at the beginning of the sequence and a number on the end if it is the same as the one on the start. Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Your specification said the sequence starts with a number followed by a lower number.  Given that, you cannot have a sequence start with [7,7,3...].  It has to be [7,3,...].